# Rx: zip List<Single<T>> to Single<List<T>>

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-java3

*Note: This problem is same for `Observable`, with more variations like `combineLatest`. So I've picked `Single` as the minimal example.*

I routinely encounter situations where there is a list of sources of same type and they all must emit before continuing. I resolve it with `zip`:

```
Single.zip(sources) { it.map { it as SomeType } }
```

This is fragile because the `Single.zip(sources, zipper)` is not type-safe so I have to coerce elements on the return value. Isn't there a built-in operator to do that?

Comment: No. It is not possible with Java's typesystem.

Comment: @akarnokd It's not possible only because of the `Object[]` instead of `List<R>`. Coercing `zip` to be type-safe is trivial in Kotlin: `inline fun <reified T : Any> zipToList(sources: Iterable<SingleSource<out T>>): Single<Iterable<T>> = Single.zip(sources) { it.map { it as T } }`. I'm asking about alternatives to zip.

Comment: There is no such operator that would do that. There were attempts at rectifying the problem but none of the proposed solution worked well enough. In kotlin though, you can do workarounds more conveniently.

Comment: `[system.reactive]` is a .NET namespace. It's not a Java Rx tag.

Comment: @Enigmativity Question is about Rx in general, not a particular implementation.

Comment: @Agent_L - Yes, which is why I removed the `[system.reactive]` tag.

Comment: @Enigmativity So why haven't you removed the [rx-java] as well ?

Comment: @Agent_L - Only because I didn't know what language the code in the question was written in. I know it's not C# though.